# Microformat combination to use with events data on a map

Tags: html, microformats

I have event data displaying on a map and I am currently using the geo microformat alongside it however it's not particularly rich to have just a list of locations without any details of what they correspond to.

I've been looking at combining microformats to achieve this and looking for some thoughts on the subject

here is the data i am marking up:
**event title**, **event location [latlong]**, **event address**, **contact phone**, **link to full details**

My initial thoughts are to use an hCard along with geo? Is there anything better?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd use [hCalendar](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar) for event data, but you don't mention having one of the required fields: a date/time. If that was just a mistake in your list, use hCalendar. If you somehow have events with no idea when they happen, hCard is probably your best bet.